# Integration test Given/When/Then Java

Tags: java, spring, integration-testing

I want to write an integration test for my service method but I have some problems with this. I have other tests which I want to use like a pattern but it's still too hard for me because in this method I have different kinds of return element:
This is my method:

```
public List<PersonWithTeamsDto> peopelWithTeamsAssigned() {
        List<Person> people = personRepository.findByTeamsNotEmpty();

        return people.stream()
                .map(person -> {
                    PersonWithTeamsDto dto = modelMapper.map(person, PersonWithTeamsDto.class);
                    dto.setTeams(mapTeams(person));
                    return dto;
                }).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

I want to test this method!!
I want to do something like this :

```
public void shouldAddPersonToTeam() {

        // Given
        TeamDto teamDto = new TeamDto(null, "Janek", "local", "wawa", 6);
        PersonDto personDto = new PersonDto(null, "janek", "mucha", "email1@onet.com", "krakow", "Programing", "Developer");
        Team team = teamService.createTeam(teamDto);
        Person person = personService.addPerson(personDto);

        // When
        final long personId = person.getId();
        teamService.addPersonsToTeams(team.getId(), personId);

        entityManager.flush();
        entityManager.clear();
        // Then
        Optional<Team> teamFromService = teamService.findTeamEntityById(team.getId());
        assertThat(teamFromService.isPresent()).isTrue();
        Set<Person> persons = teamFromService.get().getPersons();
        assertThat(persons).hasSize(1);
        assertThat(persons.stream().filter(person1 -> person1.getId() == personId).findAny()).isPresent();
    }
```

But actually I have this:

```
@Test
    @Transactional
    public void shouldReturnPeopleWithTeamsAssigned(){

        // Given
        TeamDto teamDto = new TeamDto(null, "Janek", "local", "wawa", 6);
        PersonDto personDto = new PersonDto(null, "janek", "mucha", "email1@onet.com", "krakow", "Programing", "Developer");
        Team team = teamService.createTeam(teamDto);
        Person person = personService.addPerson(personDto);

        //When
        teamService.addPersonsToTeams(team.getId(),person.getId());
        personService.peopelWithTeamsAssigned();

        entityManager.flush();
        entityManager.clear();
        //Then
        List<PersonWithTeamsDto> personWithTeamsDtos = personService.peopelWithTeamsAssigned();
        assertThat(personWithTeamsDtos.contains();

    }
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? In the first test example you're not using `peopelWIthTeamsAssigned`. And both test examples show similar structure. Could you clarify what you want to achieve and what's wrong with what you have already done?

Comment: I want to create given when than test for peopelWIthTeamsAssigned. But i don't know how to wrote then, and My question is my given and when is ok ?

Comment: this is my than: //Then
        List<PersonWithTeamsDto> personWithTeamsDtos = personService.peopelWithTeamsAssigned();
        assertThat(personWithTeamsDtos.size());

Comment: You should probably flush before calling `peopleWithTeamsAssigned`, if you want to test that the changes are persisted, since it depends on the result of `addPersonsToTeams` being stored